# Length of finite sequence of open intervals whose union contains $X = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$X = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $(I_n)$ is a finite sequence of open intervals such that $X \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{N} I_n$. Prove that: $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \ell (I_n) \geq 1$.

I’m not sure how to get started with approaching this question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to tell us?

Comment: You might try induction on $N$.

Answer (score 2):

The measure of $\bigcup_nI_n$ is at most the sum of the lengths of the intervals. If this is less than $1$, the measure is less than $1$, and thus its complement in $[0,1]$ has positive measure. Thus it contains infinitely many points. Since there are only finitely many $I_n$, at least two of these points have no $I_n$ between them. Between these two points lies a rational that's not covered by the $I_n$.

Comment: Can you explain the sentence “Since there are only finitely many $I_n$, at least two of these points have no $I_n$ between them”? I’m not quite following here / past this point.

Comment: @JaneDoe: There are infinitely many points that are not in one of the $I_n$, and thus infinitely many intervals between these points. Each of the finitely many $I_n$ lies entirely in one of these intervals (since in order to overlap two of them, it would have to contain one of the points). So infinitely many of these intervals are disjoint from the $I_n$. Between any two reals lies a rational, so there are rationals in $[0,1]$ that aren't in one of the $I_n$. The contradiction shows that, contrary to the assumption, the measure, an thus the sum of the lengths, isn't less than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $[0,1] = \overline{X} $ and $\overline{\cup_k I_k} = \cup_k \overline{I_k}$ hence
$[0,1] \subset \cup_k \overline{I_k}$. Then $1_{[0,1]} \le \sum_k 1_\overline{I_k}$ and
hence integrating gives
$1 \le \sum_k l(\overline{I_k}) $. Since $l(I_k)= l(\overline{I_k})$ we are finished.

**Note**: A slightly different approach is to pick $\epsilon>0$ and let
$I_k' = (\inf I_k-\epsilon, \sup I_k+\epsilon)$, note that the $I_k'$ cover $[0,1]$. Then $1_{[0,1]} \le \sum_k 1_{I_k'}$ and integrating gives
$1 \le \sum_l l({I_k'}) = \sum_k (l(I_k) +2 \epsilon)$. Since $\epsilon>0$
was arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Comment: This is nice, but it does require a few easily proven 'facts' about closures. I wonder if there is a different approach.

Comment: Sure, there are lots of approaches. You could extend the $I_k$ by $\epsilon$ on either side and since it contains the closure of $I_k$ the extended bunch  covers $[0,1]$ and the above reasoning follows (for all $\epsilon>0$ and hence for the unextended  collection.)

Answer (score 0):

What I tried to prove is that the union of $I_n$ is basically at least $[0,1] \setminus Z $ where $Z$ is of measure 0. I'm not 100% sure it's correct but as the other answer follows another idea(which I think is much evident) I will post just for the sake of diversity.

> You can just take the closure of $\bigcup_{n} I_n$ and it's a compact space as it's closed and bounded. We have added to the previous set a finite number of points so the measure is still the same. Take the covering of open balls $B_{\epsilon_x}(x)$ where $x \in$ the interior(add what's necessary). As it's compact it has a Lebesgue number $\epsilon$. Use this number and that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$ to finish the proof.